# Add a common query to Spring Data JPA Repository in hirachical vs flat way

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In Spring Data JPA a interface (`CommonRepository`) that contains common (not custom) querys can:

- extends `JpaRepository` so that a concreate repository only need to extend the `CommonRepository` or,
- the `CommonRepository` extends nothing and the the concreate repositories have to extends `JpaRepository` and the `CommonRepository`

which way is the preferred one?

---

Sometimes a Picture explain it best:

- The Domain Model (the common feature is that every entity has a title)

[image: Domain Model: a common class and two concrete classes]

- Repositories

I want not to write the `findByTitle(String title)` method explicit for every repository *(In truth there is not only the one common query, but much more)*.
With Spring Data JPA, it seams possible to solve this in two different ways:

- **Hierarchical way**: `MyCommonRepository` extends the `JpaRepository`

[image: Hierarchical way]

```
public interface MyCommonRepository<T extends TitledEntity<T>,
                                    ID extends Serializable>
                       extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {...}

public interface DomainClassARepository
                       extends MyCommonRepository<DomainClassA, Long> {...}
```

- **Flat way:** `MyCommonRepository` extends nothing, but the concrete Repositories have to extend `JpaRepository` and `MyCommonRepository`.

[image: Flat way]

```
public interface MyCommonRepository<T extends TitledEntity<T>> {...}

public interface DomainClassARepository
                         extends JpaRepository<DomainClassA, Long>,
                                 MyCommonRepository<DomainClassA> {...}
```

From a first test both ways seams to work, **but I don't know if there is some pitfall or some other reason to de?**

Answer (score 1):

It would be a better idea to use **Hierarchical Way** if all of repositories need to extend `JpaRepository` rather than `PagingAndSortingRepository` or `CrudRepository` for different repositories.

However, the **Flat Way** gives more freedom as different repositories can extends different type of *JPA Repositories*. Again, the flat way is more verbose than hierarchical way.